Dynamic Hierarchical dropdown list boxes design
We have a UI that involves several sequential dropdown where the options available in one depends on the selection in the preceding box.  This works well enough in practice but some changes have been requested and we have minor concerns about the usability of the interface.
We are developing a frontend service for multiple background object stores (S3, GCP, etc).
We our storage is categorized as Realm-Provider-Region-StorageClass.  Each backend cluster we support is assigned one or more values for each category (for example we support us-central1 and us-east1 in GCP).

When creating a new bucket in our user interface, the user is prompted to make a Realm selection from a dropdown listbox, then the next dropdown box appears for Provider, and so on.  Only the options available are displayed in a given dropdown.  For example, when selecting 'gcp' as the provider, 'us-east1' and 'us-central1' are the options for region, but when when selecting 'tpc' as the provider, only 'us-central1' is an option.


This brings us to my question.  The current behavior is that the sole option in a dropdown is selected by default, while those that have multiple options have nothing selected. There has been some discussion about instead disabling the drops downs that only have a single option, making them unelectable/uneditable.  However, this results in the "down the line" dropdowns randomly toggling the disabled view state depending on what options are available.
In other words for drop-down numbered 1-4:

User selects option A from #2.  #3 turns grey, #4 is selectable
User changes selection to option B in #2.  #3 becomes selectable, #4 turns grey

The net effect is that when a user is trying to explore their options, the drop-down are constantly changing edit state and sort of appear like "twinkling lights"

There are pros and cons to disabling the drop-down.  Obviously if there is no choice to be made, it makes sense to not present a choice to the user and disable the box.  However, since down the line boxes depend on earlier selections, it leads to an inconsistent experience and furthermore we aren't communicating well that the choices are greyed out because there is nothing to choose from.
Something like  would be great, but those don't really support multiple heirachys.
There are only a few clusters, so we could make a single dropdown box with each unique combination (this would result in 4-10 options.  E.g. 'RelamA-Provider1-useast1-gold', 'RelamA-Provider1-useast1-silver', 'RelamA-Provider2-usecentral1-gold', etc.
We could switch to a different interface mechanism altogether, but we aren't sure of what would be better.

Welcome to the site! This question reminds me of many discussions I had...

However, since down the line boxes depend on earlier selections, it leads to an inconsistent experience

What actually is "inconsistent" here? When the user can choose, there are multiple options to choose from, in a standard control. When there is only a single choice, it has been made and it's "greyed out" in a standard fashion. I see change in the UI as a reaction to a user action, but I don't see "inconsistency". Often, this is a replacement of "I don't like it", to which I reply with this video.

furthermore we aren't communicating well that the choices are greyed out because there is nothing to choose from.

Do you have user research results saying that this interaction is not understood by your users? If so, you could extend your design by an annotation on a disabled drop-down list saying "Because of previous choice, there only this one option", but as long as you don't, I think the dynamic behavior communicates the mechanism quite well (I change first option, second option changes).

I agree with Nobi, about that the interface explains by itself on how it interacts with the user when certain response is selected from the dropdown list.
I had a similar problem with a table that grayed out a textfield if a certain variable was selected (similar interaction). I was in charge of that flow and "I didn't like" the behavior so when our researcher tested out the flow the question I wanted to ask was, how do you feel about the x textfield?. Users didn't matter about the functionality of the grayed out and they understood that it was pre-filled because it was related to the selection they did on the related list. The only changed that I did was based on a feedback to include an i icon just for those that wondered why it was pre-filled explaining why it was grayed out.
Dev team added a listener on the icon to see the percentage of users that use the icon to decide to keep it or removed it and it was variable over the following weeks of its release: 46% ... 54% ... 47% ... so the team decided to keep it.
Hope this answer help you to clear the water.
